# Computing the circumference of two circles

Tags: java

This is a program which computes the circumference of two circles and gives some information such as the difference between circumferences.  I want to know whether the method declarations and method calling in my code is correct.  I didn't face any errors.

```
import java.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class Q5Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        double smallCircum;
        double largeCircum;
        InputHandler input = new InputHandler();
        Question5 myq = new Question5();

        double a = input.getDouble("Radius for the smaller circle:");

        smallCircum = (myq.start(a));//calculate the small circle circumference


        a = input.getDouble("Radius for the larger circle: ");
        largeCircum = (myq.start(a));//calculate the large circle circumference

        myq.showDetails(smallCircum, largeCircum);


    }


}


class Question5{
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.000");

    private double circumference;//to store circumference

    //carry out the full process
    public double start(double value){
        return circum(value);
    }




    //compute the circumference
    private double circum(double radius){
        circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
        return circumference;
    }


    public void showDetails(double smallCircum, double largeCircum){
        System.out.println("Circumference of smaller circle: "+df.format(smallCircum));
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Circumference of larger circle: "+df.format(largeCircum));
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Difference: "+df.format((largeCircum-smallCircum)));

    }

}





class InputHandler{
    private static final String DOUBLE_DEFAULT_PROMPT = "Enter integer: ";

    public double getDouble(){
        return getDouble(DOUBLE_DEFAULT_PROMPT);
    }

    public static double getDouble(String prompt){
        String inStr;
        inStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,prompt);
        return Double.parseDouble(inStr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although your code works, it's not so good.

#### Declare variables as late as possible

Here you declare some variables at the top, and use them much later, for example `smallCircum`:

> ```
> double smallCircum;
> double largeCircum;
> InputHandler input = new InputHandler();
> Question5 myq = new Question5();
>
> double a = input.getDouble("Radius for the smaller circle:");
>
> smallCircum = (myq.start(a));//calculate the small circle circumference
> ```

It would be better to declare as late as possible, right before you need it:

```
InputHandler input = new InputHandler();
Question5 myq = new Question5();

double a = input.getDouble("Radius for the smaller circle:");
double smallCircum = (myq.start(a));//calculate the small circle circumference
```

#### Pointless field

In `Question5`, the variable `circumference` doesn't need to be a field.
It's only used here:

> ```
> private double circum(double radius){
>     circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
>     return circumference;
> }
> ```

But there is no need to store that value in a field, and no need for even a local variable, you can simply return it directly:

```
private double circum(double radius) {
    return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
}
```

#### `static` method

It's unclear why this method in `InputHandler` is `static`:

> ```
> public static double getDouble(String prompt){
> ```

I suggest to drop the `static` keyword, make it non-static.

#### Poor naming

Looking at this:

> ```
> smallCircum = (myq.start(a));//calculate the small circle circumference
> ```

A method named `start` returns the calculated circumference.
That's really not intuitive.
Why not rename `start` to `calculateCircum`?
If its containing `Question5` class needs to be kept general purpose and not imply circumference, then perhaps you can rename the method to just `calculate` instead.
Probably almost anything is better than `start`.

Another thing, `a` is a poor name to store `radius`.

#### Make `private` what you can

In `Question5`, `df` should be `private`.

#### Make `final` what you can

In `Question5`, `df` can be `final`.

#### Suggested implementation

With the above suggestions applied, the solution becomes:

package com.janosgyerik.practice.oj.leetcode.hard.SubstringWithConcatenationOfAllWords;

```
class Q5Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        InputHandler input = new InputHandler();
        Question5 myq = new Question5();

        double smallRadius = input.getDouble("Radius for the smaller circle:");
        double smallCircum = myq.calculate(smallRadius);

        double largeRadius = input.getDouble("Radius for the larger circle: ");
        double largeCircum = myq.calculate(largeRadius);

        myq.showDetails(smallCircum, largeCircum);
    }
}    

class Question5 {
    private final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.000");

    public double calculate(double value) {
        return circum(value);
    }

    private double circum(double radius) {
        return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
    }

    public void showDetails(double smallCircum, double largeCircum) {
        System.out.println("Circumference of smaller circle: " + df.format(smallCircum));
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Circumference of larger circle: " + df.format(largeCircum));
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Difference: " + df.format((largeCircum - smallCircum)));
    }
}    

class InputHandler {
    private static final String DOUBLE_DEFAULT_PROMPT = "Enter integer: ";

    public double getDouble() {
        return getDouble(DOUBLE_DEFAULT_PROMPT);
    }

    public double getDouble(String prompt) {
        String inStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, prompt);
        return Double.parseDouble(inStr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

janos gave a great answer.  I would add that you should validate user input before calculation to make sure the string they enter is an integer of the size you expect.